# Using Where clause in a join, with Group by and Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm using the MySQL classicmodels database. The following query works fine (note the where clause)

```
select 
    customers.customerNumber as 'Customer ID',
    customers.customerName as 'Customer Name',
    count(orders.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders Placed'
from customers
left join orders on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
where customers.customerNumber > 200
group by
    customers.customerNumber
order by 
    3 asc
```

But the following results in an error. The intention is to display only those customers in the resulting set of rows, who have placed more than 3 orders. What am I doing wrong?

```
select 
    customers.customerNumber as 'Customer ID',
    customers.customerName as 'Customer Name',
    count(orders.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders Placed'
from customers
left join orders on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
where count(orders.orderNumber) > 3
group by
    customers.customerNumber
order by 
    3 asc
```

MySQL error is: **Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aggregate functions (`COUNT(), AVG(), SUM(),` etc) cannot appear in the `WHERE` clause, owing to when they are calculated.  Instead, they belong in a `HAVING` clause:

```
select 
    customers.customerNumber as 'Customer ID',
    customers.customerName as 'Customer Name',
    count(orders.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders Placed'
from customers
left join orders on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
group by
    customers.customerNumber
HAVING count(orders.orderNumber) > 3
order by 
    3 asc
```

Comment: And since we want customers with more than 3 orders, there's no harm in turning that `left join` to `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way would be to move the group by aggregation into a nested derived table and join that.

```
SELECT 
  c.customerNumber AS 'Customer ID',
  c.customerName AS 'Customer Name',
  o.orderCount AS 'Total Orders Placed'
FROM 
  customers c
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     customerNumber, 
     COUNT(*) AS orderCount
   FROM
     orders
   GROUP BY
     customerNumber) o
 ON
   c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
 WHERE
   o.orderCount > 3
 ORDER BY
   3
```

Comment: Whether it will be more or less efficient (or if it doesn't matter and the optimizer will figure out and convert internally one query to the other) depends on the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an indirect way to use aggregate function in where clause

You may rewrite the query as

```
select customers.customerNumber as 'Customer ID',
       customers.customerName as 'Customer Name',
       count(orders.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders Placed'
  from customers left join orders on customers.customerNumber =
                                     orders.customerNumber
 where
 (SELECT CASE
        WHEN count(orders.orderNumber) > 3 THEN
             'TRUE'
        ELSE
             'FALSE'
        END
   FROM DUAL) = 'TRUE'
 group by customers.customerNumber
 order by 3 asc
```

Here, the count function is used within the select clause, which returns TRUE of FALSE string as per count calculation.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
select 
  customers.customerNumber as 'Customer ID',
  customers.customerName as 'Customer Name',
  count(orders.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders Placed'
from customers
inner join orders on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
group by
  customers.customerNumber, 
  customers.customerName
having count(orders.orderNumber) > 3
order by 
  3 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's simplified version of what you're trying to achieve.

```
SELECT 
    customers.customerName,
    COUNT(orders.orderNumber) totalOrders
FROM
    customers
        JOIN
    orders ON customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
GROUP BY customers.customerName
HAVING totalOrders > 2;
```

[image]